# Create a Responsive Div with 900px width?

Tags: html, css, responsive

i am not a web developer, i do it for fun, so i have a question...

How to turn a div with 900px into a responsive when i lower screen resolution?

Here is my code (i am new at coding):

```css
.container
{
  width: 900px;
  background-color: #fda2a2;
}

.headline
{
  padding: 5px 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.text
{
  padding: 5px 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="headline">Column title</h3> 
  <p class="text">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p> 
</div>
```

I don't want to put a percentage at width (`.container`)... Anyone know how to do this? :)

Comment: You could try using bootstrap..

Comment: please refer this link for responsive design http://stackoverflow.com/a/35605310/5383669

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`media query`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

> The @media rule is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices.

```css
.container
{
  width: 900px;
  background-color: #fda2a2;
}

.headline
{
  padding: 5px 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.text
{
  padding: 5px 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .container {
      width:100%;  
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="headline">Column title</h3> 
  <p class="text">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: My pleasure :) Please accept one of the answers so it will help to other people (you can upvote too for people who take their time to help you ;))

Comment: You right Mosh it's not like we working here but we sacrifice our ti me to help :(

Comment: Of course i wanted to "upvote" but when i click it says that "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change publicly displayed post score."

I am new here, when i will receive those "reputation points" of course i will upvote...

Comment: You are right @DanielDiaz. But can you accept an answer? When you accept an answer other people with same problem will know that this is a tested and trusted solution. Also, when you accept an answer you get 2 reputation..

Answer (score 2):

You should use `max-width` instead of `width`.

```css
.container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fda2a2;
}

.headline {
    padding: 5px 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
.text {
    padding: 5px 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3 class="headline">Column title</h3> 
    <p class="text">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a combination of `width` and `max-width`. No need for media queries

```
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 900px;
  background-color: #fda2a2;
}
```

or

```
.container {
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fda2a2;
}
```

This way the `.container` will never be bigger than the screen width, and can't become bigger than `900px`

Comment: @DanielDiaz glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using px its hard to manage it in responsive. So either go with percentage. If you need to use px itself, then you can use media query and mention the respective px using media query for various sizes.

Refer this, http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
You can accomplish this by using media queries for like

/* Make sure your standard css is always on top of media queries */

    .container
    {
      width: 900px;
      background-color: #fda2a2;
    }

    .headline
    {
      padding: 5px 30px;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Helvetica;
    }
    .text
    {
      padding: 5px 30px;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-family: Helvetica;
    }

    Then below you need to set the style for each screen size and behaviour e.g

    /* Portrait and Landscape */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 320px) 
      and (max-device-width: 480px)
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
      .container{
        background-color:red;
    }

    /* Portrait */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 320px) 
      and (max-device-width: 480px)
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
      and (orientation: portrait) {
.container{
        background-color:yellow;
    }
    }

    /* Landscape */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 320px) 
      and (max-device-width: 480px)
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
      and (orientation: landscape) {
    .container{
        background-color:black;
    }
    }
```

for different types of media queries that supports different devices check here [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: /* Make sure your standard css is always on top of media queries */
Thats why i failed several times :) Thank you for your advice!

Comment: That's why I posted it as an answer to be rated.